# Local variable not changing

Tags: c#, variables, xna, local

I currently have an issue regarding local variables in a method. The method is made to spawn a line of square sprites along the bottom of the screen.The code currently looks like so:

```
 public void spawnFloor()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < floorSize / texture.Width; x++)
        {
            if (walls.Count < floorSize / texture.Width)
            {
                positionModifier.X = texture.Width * x;
                position.Y = floorStart.Y;
                spawnWall();
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, when the game resolution is 1280/720, the game spawns 40 squares at the bottom right corner of the screen. The value of x is apparently 0 throughout. Any ideas? Below is the code of the class in it's entirety in case it's something class based:

```
    public WallManager(Texture2D texture, Vector2 floorStart, int screenLength)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.floorStart = floorStart;
        floorSize = screenLength;
    }

    public void spawnWall()
    {
        Wall thisWall = new Wall(position*positionModifier, texture);
        walls.Add(thisWall);
    }

    public void spawnTest()
    {
        if (walls.Count == 0)
        {
            position = new Vector2(0, 698);
            spawnWall();
        }
    }

    public void spawnFloor()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < floorSize / texture.Width; x++)
        {
            if (walls.Count < floorSize / texture.Width)
            {
                positionModifier.X = texture.Width * x;
                position.Y = floorStart.Y;
                spawnWall();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach(Wall wall in walls)

        wall.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

Edit: As suggested, the wall class has been posted:

```
public Wall(Vector2 position, Texture2D texture)
    {
        wallPosition = position;
        wallTexture = texture;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        wallWidth = (int)Math.Round((double)wallTexture.Width);
        wallHeight = (int)Math.Round((double)wallTexture.Height);
        wallHitbox = new Rectangle((int)wallPosition.X, (int)wallPosition.Y, wallWidth, wallHeight);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(wallTexture, wallPosition, wallColor);
    }
```

Also, positionModifier is a private Vector2 in the wallManager class with the value (1,1) on startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to tell whats broken based on the code you have posted. The issue is most likely in how `Wall` is being created. I would bet that either `positionModifier.X` does not actually do anything to the x position of the wall, or that the starting value for the walls x position is 0 and when you multiply `positionModifier` with it in the method call, it remains 0.

Comment: Yeap. Turns out the starting value of position.x was 0. After setting it to the texture width & using the whole vector instead of the Y value of floorStart, the script works as intended. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Because it is doing `Closures` inside your loop. Copy a local variable for the value of `x` and store it as `localVal` (example) and then use that one when calculating your positionModifier

```
public void spawnFloor()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < floorSize / texture.Width; x++)
    {
        if (walls.Count < floorSize / texture.Width)
        {
            var localVal = x;
            positionModifier.X = texture.Width * localVal;
            position.Y = floorStart.Y;
            spawnWall();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Afraid that didn't work. Like I said, the value of x doesn't change at all, even though it should cycle through the values 0-40. Since that happens, now localVal stays at 0 throughout.
As an FYI, the value of floorSize is set to the horizontal resolution, which is 1280 in this case